# JAXBContext: How to dynamically load objects based on particular attribute?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have three versions of xml with same root element name and child element will vary on each version.

> Note: In my application, we are using large xml. So I simplified the
> examples below but the requirement is exactly same.

Sample XMLs below:

```
<Tutorial version="1.0">
    <FieldA>aaa</FieldA>
    <FieldB>bbb</FieldB>
    <FieldC>ccc</FieldC>
</Tutorial>

<Tutorial version="2.0">
    <FieldD>ddd</FieldD>
    <FieldE>eee</FieldE>
    <FieldF>fff</FieldF>
</Tutorial>

<Tutorial version="3.0">
    <FieldG>ggg</FieldG>
    <FieldH>hhh</FieldH>
    <FieldI>iii</FieldI>
</Tutorial>
```

I have three different data structure for each version like below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.Field)
@XmlRootElement(name="Tutorial")
public class Tutorialv1
{
@XmlElement(name="FieldA")
String fieldA;
@XmlElement(name="FieldB")
String fieldB;
@XmlElement(name="FieldC")
String fieldC;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.Field)
@XmlRootElement(name="Tutorial")
public class Tutorialv2
{
@XmlElement(name="FieldD")
String fieldD;
@XmlElement(name="FieldE")
String fieldE;
@XmlElement(name="FieldF")
String fieldF;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.Field)
@XmlRootElement(name="Tutorial")
public class Tutorialv3
{
@XmlElement(name="FieldG")
String fieldG;
@XmlElement(name="FieldH")
String fieldH;
@XmlElement(name="FieldI")
String fieldI;
}
```

Based on the version attribute of Tutorial element, I have to populate respective data structure. Now I am using JAXB to parse the xml into objects but prior to that I am checking the version using regex like below:

```
private final Pattern VERSION_REGEX=Pattern.compile("<Tutorial version=\"([^\"]+|)");
String version = null;
Matcher versionMatcher=VERSION_REGEX.matcher(xmlSource);
if(versionMatcher.find()) {
    version = versionMatcher.group(1);
}

Reader reader = new StringReader(xmlSource);
XMLStreamReader xmlReader = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);

switch (version) {
    case "1.0":
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tutorialv1.class).createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Tutorialv1> tutorial = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, Tutorialv1.class);

        return otherBusinessLogicGoesHere(tutorial);
    case "2.0":
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tutorialv2.class).createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Tutorialv2> tutorial = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, Tutorialv2.class);
        
        return otherBusinessLogicGoesHere(tutorial);
    case "3.0":
    default:
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tutorialv3.class).createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBElement<Tutorialv3> tutorial = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlReader, Tutorialv3.class);
        
        return otherBusinessLogicGoesHere(tutorial);
}
```

As of now, I used above solution but I feel that it is not good idea to check version using regex. Is there any other solution available to dynamically load objects based on version attribute using JAXB parser?